# Python template include a page if condition

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, boilerplate

i'm developing a small app with Python and Google app engine. I'm using boilerplate (https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate) as front-end which follows gae direction and python templates, so nothing diffrent than plain stuff.

Now, what i would like to have is this.
When a user logged in, if the field of name and last name are not filled in i would like to have, in the home page, the profile editing.

The page for editing the profile is a template (which extend the base.html), called edit_profile.html which works well.
The homepage is a template as well (extend the base.html) called home.html.

Now, can i include the edit_profile.html in home.html? how can i do it?

this is what i've, i don't know what to put instead of ???? i tried with

```
 {% block edit_profile.html %}  {% endblock %}
```

but does not work

```
{% if user_info.name and user_info.last_name %}
        ..
        {% else %}
           ????
        {% endif %}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to include only some block of given template. There are two solutions:

1) Create template just for profile editing form and include it into `edit_profile.html`. Then include it also into  `home.html` to `if` condition branch:

profile_form.html:

```
<form action="{% url some-action %}">
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="save"/>
</form
```

profile_edit.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block main %}
{% include "profile_form.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

home.html

```
{% if user_info.name and user_info.last_name %}
{% include "profile_form.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

2) use variable for extended template:

profile_form.html

```
{% extend BASE_TEMPLATE %}
```

and set it into context w/ different value as needed:

in home.html (let's say `included_form.html` is some basic template)

```
{% if user_info.name and user_info.last_name %}
{% with "included_form.html" as BASE_TEMPLATE %}
   {% include "edit_profile.html" %}
{% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

and if you want show form as a standalone page, set `BASE_TEMPLATE` to `base.html`

Comment: mmm. seems that i've to rewrite the templates that are provided by the  boilerplate.
The second method does not work, maybe i did something wrong. 
Anyway, to make the example clearer, what i want to include inside my page is what's inside the content block of this tempalte https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate/blob/master/templates/boilerplate_edit_profile.html

can i say to the template to include the content block of that file?

Comment: Can i say to the template to include the content block of that file? - no